# Python: Why are my integers being converted to strange negative numbers at np.genfromtxt read in

Tags: python, arrays, user-defined-types

**Why is python inserting strange negative numbers into my array?**

I am reading some numerical data from a plain text file like below:

```
fp=np.genfromtxt("mytextfile.txt", dtype=('int32'), delimiter='\r\n')
```

The information contained in the file are all positive numbers, file is formatted like below and there are 300000 of these numbers:

```
12345
45678
1056789
232323
6789010001
1023242556
```

When I print out the fp read in array, the first half of the array is correctly read in but the last half is strange negative numbers that aren't in my file at all.

How can I get it to read correctly what is in the file?

Comment: The maximum size of a 32 bit signed integer is `2147483647` - `6789010001` is bigger than this so you are overflowing. Use `int64`.

Comment: @AChampion Great Thanks! That was it. Wish you had posted this so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have data larger then int32 can save, this causes overflow and makes it negative.

Numpy's Integers doesn't act like python's integer it's like a C integer

Try change dtype from int32 to int64 or object may help

Answer (score 3):

You told it the numbers are `int32`s, but at least some of your numbers, e.g. 6789010001 are larger than a signed 32 bit quantity can represent (6789010001 is larger than an unsigned 32 bit quantity can represent).

If all the numbers are positive, I'd suggested using `uint64` as your data type (you should check that all numbers in the file are in fact less than `2**64` though).

Comment: Good to know...I'll try uint64 instead. Thanks @ShadowRanger